# python multiprocessing pool: how can I know when all the workers in the pool have finished?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I am running a multiprocessing pool in python, where I have ~2000 tasks, being mapped to 24 workers with the pool.
each task creates a file based on some data analysis and webservices.

I want to run a new task, when all the tasks in the pool were finished. how can I tell when all the processes in the pool have finished?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You want to use [the `join` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join), which halts the main process thread from moving forward until all sub-processes ends:

> Block the calling thread until the process whose join() method is called terminates or until the optional timeout occurs.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print 'hello', name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    processes = []
    for i in range(10):
        p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
        processes.append(p)

    for p in processes:
        p.start()
        p.join()

     # only get here once all processes have finished.
     print('finished!')
```

**EDIT:**

To use [`join` with pools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.join)

```
    pool = Pool(processes=4)  # start 4 worker processes
    result = pool.apply_async(f, (10,))  # do some work
    pool.close()
    pool.join()  # block at this line until all processes are done
    print("completed")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am asking about the pool method: where you let the multiprocessing to start the processes automatically. how can you do this "join" trick with the pool?

Comment: Ok updated answer. You just call `join()` on the `pool` instance.

Comment: Note that you need to call `pool.close()` or `pool.terminate()` before you can call `pool.join()`, so the example above won't actually work. Also note that using `join()` to tell when the work is done is only a viable option if you don't need to use the pool anymore afterward, since it requires closing or terminating the pool.

Comment: how to re-open pool after pool.join() ?

Comment: If you want the processes to run in parallel you need to first call start() on all the processes and then call join.

Comment: This accepted answer is **NOT** running in parallel, therefore is not a valid answer.

Comment: Each of the `apply_async` runs a pool on one process only!! So this answer is **NOT*** running in parallel!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `wait()` method of the `ApplyResult` object (which is what `pool.apply_async` returns).

```
import multiprocessing

def create_file(i):
    open(f'{i}.txt', 'a').close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # The default for n_processes is the detected number of CPUs
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:

        # Launch the first round of tasks, building a list of ApplyResult objects
        results = [pool.apply_async(create_file, (i,)) for i in range(50)]
    
        # Wait for every task to finish
        [result.wait() for result in results]

        # {start your next task... the pool is still available}

    # {when you reach here, the pool is closed}
```

This method works even if you're planning on using your pool again and don't want to close it--as an example, you might want to keep it around for the next iteration of your algorithm. Use a `with` statement or call `pool.close()` manually when you're done using it, or bad things will happen.